# How to keep the cell highlighted while editing

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I have a developed a custom drop-down renderer and drop-down cell editor. When the cell is highlighted by single clicking, the following css is applied to get the effect as shown in picture

[image]

```
.ag-cell:focus {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid blue !important;
}
```

I would like to have the same css on the cell when it is being edited by double clicking the cell. At present, the cell highlighting is missing as shown in the below image

[image]

Comment: its hard to notice the difference between both screenshots, may be needs better cropping or more details

Comment: The first image(when "qww" cell is focused) has the blue border around it and that border is missing in the second image(when "qww" cell is in edit mode).  Please let me know if you still require a few more details.