# increase height of a specific row

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

Initially, all rows will have the same height of 50. When a cell is focused,if it has more content and requires more height, I need to increase the height of that particular cell. If that is not possible, atleast that entire particular row's height has to be increased. The remaining rows should not get effected.

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of `rowSelection` api particularly the **selected** property of each `rowNode`.

You can define `getRowHeight` in html `[getRowHeight]="getRowHeight"`
and `(selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"`

And define `getRowHeight` like this -

```
this.getRowHeight = function(params) {
  return params.node.selected ? 100 : 50; // if selected height is 100 else default 50
}
```

and then in your `onSelectionChanged`,

```
  onSelectionChanged() {
    this.gridApi.resetRowHeights();
  }
```

The reason you would want to piggyback on `selected` attribute is because it is maintained by ag-grid for each row.
You could do something similar by implementing  the callback `onCellFocused` but then you will have to maintain a similar attribute for each row because you also need to adjust the height once the focused row is out of focus which might be an expensive operation.